# Difference between Flashback Query and Serializable Transaction Mode?

Tags: oracle, transaction, flashback

Is there any conceptual difference between a `SERIALIZABLE` Transaction and a Flashback Query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are completely unrelated concepts.

- Serializable is a type of [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) (read [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3233191441609) for more info)
- [Flashback Query](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=210) is an Oracle technology for getting querying data as it was at a certain point in time - for example, if certain conditions are met you can use Flashback Query to get those million rows back after committing that transaction that accidentally deleted them.

Comment: "querying data as it was at a certain point in time" ... and with an isolation level of `serializable` I'm seeing the data as it was at the beginning of my transaction, regardless of any commits in other session, right? That's why I thought they are conceptually related ...

Comment: I see your point - they are similar in that sense, but used for very different purposes, serializable to ["give each serializable transaction a "frozen" picture of the 
database at the point in time the transaction began"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3233191441609#3246716199098) and flashback typically to save your blushes when something has gone awry